# How does polymers observe-js works?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at the code of [Polymers observe-js](https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js/blob/master/src/observe.js), and I can't quite grasp how it works. I'm not talking about the dirty checking, but on the invocation of it - when does the check being performed?

It looks like the magic is here:

```
var runEOM = hasObserve ? (function(){
return function(fn) {
  return Promise.resolve().then(fn);
}
})() :
(function() {
  return function(fn) {
    eomTasks.push(fn);
  };
})();
```

Since Promise.resolve().then(fn) invokes fn at the end of the callback stack this line defers fs, similarly to setTimeout(0, fn) or process.nextTick(fn)

But runEOM is never used in the file!

Can anybody spread light on this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that dirty checking is performed manually from the outside by calling the `global.Platform.performMicrotaskCheckpoint` interface method: Line [792](https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js/blob/master/src/observe.js#L792)

I think the concept is to notify observers manually after some piece of initial job is done or something in that clue.